# Single word for the complete collection of all family created media assets (photos and videos)

Tags: single-word-requests

I have terabytes of digitized family pictures and home videos. I am organizing them and having trouble naming the root folder for all the digital assets. The word "Pictures" and "Videos" by themselves is not sufficient description of all the content within that folder. Looking for a good single word that combines "Pictures" and "Videos" into a one entity. "Media" and "HomeMedia" are the ones I've come up with so far, but not crazy about them as it implies other things like music and movies which belong in an "Entertainment" folder.

Comment: You could call the "root" folder ***Family Archives*** or similar. But *any* suggestions are POB.

Comment: I don't think there's really a word for this, but, let me suggest **Family Collage**.  It's definitely inaccurate, but a [collage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage) "results from an assemblage of different forms, thus creating a new whole" which is somewhat in line with what you're going for

Answer (score 0):

You could name the root folder “Family Mementos” to include photos, videos & any other digital content that would be organized within this folder.